# Regex, а так же конвертация ASCII to UTF8 C++

Tags: c++, utf-8, ascii

В общем, картина следующая: у меня есть окно создания имени для персонажа и мне нужно решить 2 проблемы с которыми я столкнулся.

---

Проблема 1:
Я получаю имя персонажа в char, но чтобы поддерживать кириллицу (если имя персонажа присланно в Кириллице), то мне нужно использовать вот такой код, в противном случае отображаются кракозябры:

```
char szCharacterName[40];
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring ChrnameUTF8 = converter.from_bytes(szCharname);
std::string Chrname = converter.to_bytes(ChrnameUTF8);
```

Как видите, такая конструкция создает дополнительный лишний код, можно ли как то напрямую конвертировать char Кириллицу в std::string чтоб выводило Русские символы, но при этом не терять возможность поддержки и латинских (если вдруг имя персонажа состоит из Латиницы + Кириллицы, или просто Кириллица или Латиница)

---

Проблема 2:
Как я могу с помощью regex поставить ограничение на имя персонажа, ограничение по типу: только латиница + цифры + подчеркивание, только кириллица + цифры + подчеркивание. (Важно: Цифры и подчеркивания не являются обязательными, просто разрешено использовать)
Иначе говоря, что-то одно, чтобы имя персонажа не состояло из Латиницы+Кириллицы, например: "НикName" - не подходит.

Я попытался сделать так:

```
std::regex rgx_rus("^[А-Яа-я][А-Яа-яёЁ\d]*$");
std::regex rgx_eng("^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d]*$");
if ((regex_match(Chrname.begin(), Chrname.end(), rgx_eng) == true) && (regex_match(Chrname.begin(), Chrname.end(), rgx_rus) == true))
{
     // Error
}
```

Но мне кажется, эта конструкция не совсем верная, так как цифры и там и там присутствуют, подскажите, люди добрые.

Comment: UTF-8 - это не широкие строки. Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь поиском по сайту - вопросы про Unicode задавали десятки раз. Ваш конвертер стал deprecated в C++17. Рекомендую почитать http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Я не могу изменить char на wchar_t - это нарушает работу многих функций, в том числе и regex

Comment: Вы так говорите, будто я вам посоветовал использовать wchar_t

Comment: У Вас 2 вопроса в одном, так делать не нужно.

Comment: Эти два вопроса взаимосвязаны, но я уже разобрался.
Regex не работал потому что в szCharacterName лежат кракозябры, перевел их в wchar (и имя и regex), и проверка сработала

Answer (score 1):

Первое, Ваш код конвертации бессмысленен:

```
char szCharacterName[40];
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring ChrnameUTF8 = converter.from_bytes(szCharname);
std::string Chrname = converter.to_bytes(ChrnameUTF8);
```

Очевидно, что в `szCharacterName` текст уже в UTF-8, который Вы перегоняете в UCS-2(4), а потом обратно в UTF-8. Абсолютно бессмысленная процедура — просто используйте `szCharacterName`

Второе, поддержка регулярных выражений для UTF-8 строк зависит от компилятора, но если поддержка есть, то такое вот выражение должно Вам подойти:

```
^(([А-Яа-я][А-Яа-яёЁ\d]*)|([A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d]*))$
```

Comment: Дело в том, что в szCharacterName при получении с клиента лежат кракозябры, а значит в regex их не проверишь.
Пришлось использовать в regex wchar, а в бд хранить кракозябры из szCharacterName, при вытаскивании из БД форматировать в wchar для сравнений и других операции. Есть ли другой способ как запихнуть в std::string русские символы?

Comment: @Дан, в программировании нет понятия «крякозябры», есть понятие кодировки. Вот как выясните в какой кодировке что лежит и в какой Вам нужно хранить, тогда вопрос и задайте, потому что сейчас Вам невозможно ничего ответить, т.к. ничего не понятно.

Comment: Я понимаю, что такое кодировка, но не понимаю, как в программировании можно заставить в один байт запихать 2х байтовыесимволы и при этом использовать какой нибудь конвертер чтобы система могла понимать char, как UTF8

Comment: @Дан, UTF-8 однобайтовая кодировка, поэтому char ей как раз отлично подходит. Почитайте что такое UTF-8